# Can you request an S2S OAuth token using Coinbase API to make authenticated requests without user interaction?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

I'm working on developing a mobile app to buy and sell cryptocurrency, and I want to allow the user to setup recurring purchases. The user should be able to schedule their purchases, and then a service running on a server will purchase the correct amount of crypto at the correct time.

The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to handle the authentication that would allow my server to make the requests on behalf of the user. Currently, I am trying to use the Coinbase API, but I would be willing to use a different cryptocurrency API if there is one that allows for this type of authentication. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This is just an idea.  Implement the Oauth2 authentication to get an access token.  Use it as the reference for the first trade.  Then using Oauth2 functionality request a refreshed Oauth2 access token.  Repeat the process as often as necessary.

Comment: Oauth2 authentication is pretty well documented on the Coinbase API website.  Just google it to find it.   Be careful, don't  mix Coinbase and Coinbase Pro APIs.